# use of unresolved identifier error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I have implemented a vote feature in my app so that user can `vote` up a post. I am using a `collection view` and have put a `label` and a `button`. When the button is pressed the vote counts up. I have that code in the `cell view controller`.  This is my collection view controller and even though I have said that votes in the cell I have an error saying

> use of unresolved identifier votes

Stuck for many hours. Any help is appreciated..Thank you.
In the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`I have

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("newview", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewCollectionViewCell
    //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()


    // Display the country name
    if let value = posts[indexPath.row]["imageText"] as? String {
        cell.postsLabel.text = value
        println("it should be there")

    }

    // Display "initial" flag image
    var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
    cell.postsImageView.image = initialThumbnail


    // Fetch final flag image - if it exists
    if let value = posts[indexPath.row]["imageFile"] as? PFFile {

        cell.postsImageView.file = value
        cell.postsImageView.loadInBackground({ (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
            }                
        })

        //  let finalImage = tops[indexPath.row]["tops"] as? PFFile

    }
```

I get an error from this code.

```
if let value = posts[indexPath.row]["votes"] as? Int {
    if votes == nil {
        votes = 0}
        cell.votesLabel?.text = "\(votes!) votes"

 }

return cell
}
```

Also in my cell view I also have

```
@IBAction func vote(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (parseObject != nil) {
        if var votes:Int? = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
            votes!++

            parseObject!.setObject(votes!, forKey: "votes")
            parseObject!.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)               
            votesLabel?.text = "\(votes!) votes"
    }
    }}}
```

Comment: you assign the unwrapped value of `parseObject!.objectForKey("votes")` to a variable named `value`. I think it should be `votes`.

Comment: Do you mean `if var votes:Int? = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int `

Comment: Yes it should be like that

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing below lines of code

```
if let value = posts[indexPath.row]["votes"] as? Int {
if votes == nil {
    votes = 0}
}
```

with

```
if let votes = posts[indexPath.row]["votes"] as? Int {
if votes == nil {
    votes = 0}
}
```

Comment: oh Sorry I have tried that and an error pops up saying Binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type Int and nil. Also it gives an error to a pice of code           `  cell.votesLabel?.text = "\(votes!) votes"` Saying that operand of post fix ! should have optional type, Type is int

Comment: Try first `if let votes = posts[indexPath.row]["votes"] as? Int { println(votes) }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84524/discussion-between-satsuki-and-frequencymatched).